# nginx redirect rule is redirecting everything to https even for other ports

Tags: redirect, ssl, nginx, https

Hello I have this config

```
server {
    listen          82;
    server_name     myapp.mydomain.com;
    return          301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name myapp.mydomain.com
    # ... remain of the stuff here
}
```

Before that I had other websites running in ports: 80, 3000 etc... now when I access http://myapp.mydomain.com automatically redirects me to my app (as is I were invoking port 82) and if I try to access another app running on 3000 port it tries to rewrite the https://myapp.mydomain.com:3000 as well... if I use the ip it works as expected (not the ssl part).

Full config can be found at:

https://gist.github.com/angvp/363f50ff8b8d345126adaf1595cd2523

Any ideas?

Comment: Show full https server block

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok after I start digging I had this on my nginx conf:

add_header Strict-Transport-Security max-age=15768000;

This is a security measure but that was causing all the subdomains even on different ports will try always https .. the correct way should be to have different subdomains per vhost per port..